# android soft keyboard cover the EditText focused

Tags: android, keyboard

1.put edittext to bottom of screen,set EditText's gravity to right, inputtype to something like number.
2.click the edittext, soft keyboard willl show and edittext will be push up.
3.press hardware back to hide keyboard.
4.click edittext again, keyboard will show but edittext is covered by keyboard.

Did someone get this issue too?

Comment: Put all comonants inside scrollview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put all components inside the scrollview.

```
<RootView>
   <ScrollView>
     <childview>
      .
      .
      <your other views>
      .
      .
     </childview>
   </ScrollView>
</RootView>
```

then add `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"` in your manifest to the corresponding activity.